# Will this query load the whole table in memory

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

If I have a really big table will this query load the whole table in memory before it filters the resets:

```
with parent as
(
    select * from a101
)
select * from parent 
where value1 = 159
```

As you can see the parent query reference the whole table. Will this loaded in memory. This is a very simplified version of the query. The real query has a few joins to other tables. I am evaluating sql server 2012 and postgrsql.

Comment: If this for SQL Server, postgres or both? If it's only for postgres, please remove the SQL Server tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PostgreSQL (true as of 9.4, at least) [CTEs act as *optimisation fences*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/27425/7788).

The query optimiser will not flatten CTE terms into the outer query, push down qualifiers, or pull up qualifiers, even in trivial cases. So an unqualified `SELECT` inside a CTE term will always do a full table scan (or an index-only scan if there's a suitable index).

Thus, in PostgreSQL, these two things are very different indeed, as a simple `EXPLAIN` would show:

```
with parent as
(
    select * from a101
)
select * from parent 
where value1 = 159
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM a101
) AS parent
WHERE value1 = 159;
```

However, that "will scan the whole table" doesn't necessarily mean "will load the whole table in memory". PostgreSQL will use a TupleStore, which will transparently spill to a tempfile on disk as it gets larger.

The original justification was that DML in CTE terms was planned (and later implemented). If there's DML in a CTE term it's vital that its execution be predictable and complete. This may also be true if the CTE calls data-modifying functions.

Unfortunately, nobody seems to have thought *"... but what if it's just a SELECT and we want to inline it?"*.

Many in the community appear to see this as a *feature* and regularly promulgate it as a workaround for optimiser issues. I find this attitude utterly perplexing. As a result, it's going to be really hard to fix this later, because people are intentionally using CTEs when they want to prevent the optimiser from altering a query.

In other words, PostgreSQL abuses CTEs as pseudo-query-hints (along with the `OFFSET 0` hack), because project policy says real query hints aren't desired or supported.

AFAIK MS SQL Server may optimise CTE barriers, but may also choose to materialise a result set.

Answer (score 2):

I just made `EXPLAIN` for this query in PostgreSQL. Surprisingly it does sequence scan instead of index lookup:

```
 CTE Scan on parent  (cost=123.30..132.97 rows=2 width=1711)
   Filter: (value1 = 159)
   CTE parent
     ->  Seq Scan on a101  (cost=0.00..123.30 rows=430 width=2060)
```

I have a primary key index on `value1` and it is used for simple `select * from a101 where value1 = 159` query.

So, the answer is it will scan the whole table. I am surprised, I thought it will work as a view or subquery, but it does not. You can use this to use index:

```
select * from (select * from a101) parent 
where value1 = 159`
```

Answer (score 1):

No. Queries are evaluated as a whole. If you look at the execution plan you will see the filter predicate will be applied to the inner search. GIven the triviality of the outer search, I am quite sure it will be optimizd away.

Check execution plans - this is baseline knowledge and you better learn how to do that fast. Once you hit a real performance problem you will need to find out the issue and that is where execution plans come in.

Comment: This isn't true for PostgreSQL (unfortunately) in the case of CTEs.

Answer (score 0):

CTE are just language syntax to make code more readable , they have no impact on query execution performance .

When the query is executed , it will be executed according to predefined SQL Server query execution phases

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

So `WHERE` filter will be applied first and then the records will be selected so complete table would not be fetched in memory.

Comment: Is there a MS link for this order ? Thanks

Comment: In the case of SQL Server this is incorrect. For example a particular predicate in the WHERE clause might be pushed down to an index seek which means the order you've proposed there is incorrect. It does things in whatever order the query plan tells it to. It in extreme cases it might seek based on the where clause, do an order by, then group, then merge join etc. The amount of data in memory is a function of available memory, caching etc. If there isn't any free physical memory, none of it will be loaded into memory, it'll go to the page file, regardless of the query.

Comment: This is also completely false in PostgreSQL.